# Keyboard hiding UIView iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I know this question has been asked a few times. I understand how to move the view up or a textfield up when the keyboard is presented, however I am running into a glitch that I cannot seem to figure out.

The view I am trying to move up is inside a UIViewController that acts as a container for two views. This container is itself a view inside a sliding view controller (kind of like the one Facebook implements).

The text field moves up fine when you first load the view however if you go to a different view and come back, the keyboard causes the view to disappear.

Here is the code I am using to move the view up:

```
    - (void) animateTextField:(BOOL)up {

    const int movementDistance = 350; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];

    self.sendingToolbar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.sendingToolbar.frame, 0, movement);
    self.messagesTable.frame = CGRectOffset(self.messagesTable.frame, 0, movement);
    //[splitController moveViewUp:up];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    NSLog(@"was this method called");

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    [self animateTextField:YES];
}
// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    [self animateTextField:NO];
}
```

Any ideas why this glitch might be happening? Thanks

After adding the suggestion for a boolean to check if the text field is already up the view disappears all the time when the keyboard is shown and not just when you leave the view and come back. Here is the revised method:

```
- (void) animateTextField:(BOOL)up {

    const int movementDistance = 350; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0; // tweak as needed

    int movement = movementDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];

    if(textFieldIsUp && (up == YES)) {
        NSLog(@"Case 1");
        // Do nothing since text field is already up
    }
    else if(textFieldIsUp && (up == NO)) {
        NSLog(@"Case 2");
        // Move the text field down
        self.sendingToolbar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.sendingToolbar.frame, 0, -movement);
        self.messagesTable.frame = CGRectOffset(self.messagesTable.frame, 0, -movement);

        textFieldIsUp = NO;
    }
    else if((textFieldIsUp == NO) && (up == YES)) {
        NSLog(@"Case 3");
        // Move the text field up
        self.sendingToolbar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.sendingToolbar.frame, 0, movement);
        self.messagesTable.frame = CGRectOffset(self.messagesTable.frame, 0, movement);

        textFieldIsUp = YES;
    }
    else if((textFieldIsUp == NO) && (up == NO)) {
        NSLog(@"Case 4");
        // Do nothing since the text field is already down
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Default");
        // Default catch all case. Does nothing
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Here are some more details about my setup:

The view controller is a messaging center for the app. The view controller contains two subviews the subview on the left side is a menu for picking the conversation and the right menu is a subview with the messages within that conversation. Since I want the messages to load from the bottom up, the table view is rotated 180 degrees and the cells are also rotated 180 degrees the opposite direction. Also the table view reloads every 5 seconds using an NSTimer so that the messages can be updated with any new messages.

Comment: Instead of using an `NSTimer` you should look into key-value observation. It's generally bad practice to auto-check for updates with a timer in the background (pretty inefficient).

Comment: I will look into that. Will that work well with checking for new messages using a REST service? I assumed that the array that contains the messages will have to be updated constantly from the server. I also would like to find a way to update the table of messages without having to redraw the entire table. I guess this would work if I did this key-value observation.

Comment: If you're using a server you should let the user decide when they want to update their messages. Drawing from a server consumes a non-trivial amount of overhead. I don't know of a way to update a table without redrawing the table. KVO is for looking at the properties of an object and calling some method when the properties change, so I'm not sure if it will do what you want. Try to see what you can do with it and post another question on SO if you need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textfield has already been moved up but didn't move back down when you left the view. When you revisit the view it gets moved up again - and off the screen.

I've had this problem before; solved it by keeping a boolean variable the indicated whether the textfield was in the up or down position. Check the variable to make sure the textfield isn't already up before you move it up again.

How I did it. I'm using an `NSNumber` property on my view to store whether the view has been pushed up or not so that other views can communicate whether they have pushed the view up or down.

```
//In viewDidLoad
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

//Pushes the view up if one of the table forms is selected for editing
- (void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    if ([isRaised boolValue] == NO)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y-moveAmount);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        isRaised = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
    }
}

//Push view back down
- (void) keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    if ([isRaised boolValue])
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y+moveAmount);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        isRaised = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
    }
}
```

**-EDIT-**

Looking at your code it appears that you're subtracting from the y-coordinate of a frame to move frame down. The iOS coordinate system for `CGRect` is not the same as a normal coordinate system - the y-axis is flipped (this is relatively common for graphic systems). You're going to want to do the opposite of what you're doing.

Comment: When I leave the view, the keyboard becomes hidden. Shouldn't that have called the keyboardWillBeHidden method and thus animateTextField? I logged if the method was called and I am noticing that the animateTextField method is being called twice every time a keyboard event is registered.

Comment: The `keyboardWillBeHidden` notification only gets called if you're still on the same view when the hiding happens.

Comment: I will add the condition for the boolean and let you know what happens, thanks so far for the detailed answer.

Comment: Now the view disappears whenever the keyboard is shown. I logged the method to check if my cases were correct and they seem to be correct. I edited my question with the updated method.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I log the visibility state? By logging location do you mean just log the CGRect of the Frame?

Comment: I redid the logs with your suggestion:

2012-07-30 10:45:50.161 [880:fb03] Sending Toolbar state: <UIToolbar: 0x6ccc320; frame = (0 1010; 704 44); autoresize = W+TM; animations = { position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x6ebcd50>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x6cb7270>>

2012-07-30 10:45:50.161 [880:fb03] Messages table state: <UITableView: 0x7aaea00; frame = (0 350; 704 660); transform = [-1, 0, -0, -1, 0, 0]; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; animations = { position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x6e8b0d0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x6ccd420>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

Comment: I don't really know what your setup is, but it looks like you moved your tableview down... (it's at 0, 350). Subtracting from the y-loc of a `CGRect` moves things UP and adding moves things DOWN. So that's probably your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks to be working now that I changed my movement to negative the values I had. If you add the last comment to your answer I can go ahead and accept it.